# does jquery fancy box support mp3s?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

does jquery fancy box support mp3s?
if not is there a a stable plugin?

Comment: fancybox is a modalbox plugin to display html elements. What do you mean "support mp3"? via html5's `<audio>`?

Comment: no, just wondering if i could force this to play an mp3 file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/